# How to I view internal storage on AVD in Android Studio 3.1.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am having trouble finding the option to view a virtual devices internal storage in Android 3.1.3. I know it used to be under tools and in the Android section but I am not seeing it now. I apologize if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the location for the Android Device File Explorer is now under `View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer` in Android Studio 3.1.3 (on OSX)

Comment: There is also a Device File Explorer tab on the bottom right side of the IDE